# What's the difference between Stanford Tagger, Parser and CoreNLP?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm currently using different tools from Stanford NLP Group and trying to understand the differences between them. It seems to me that somehow they intersect each other, since I can use same features in different tools (e.g. tokenize, and POS-Tag a sentence can be done by Stanford POS-Tagger, Parser and CoreNLP).

I'd like to know what's the actual difference between each tool and in which situations I should use each of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All Java classes from the same release are the same, and, yes, they overlap. On a code basis, the parser and tagger are basically subsets of what is available in CoreNLP, except that they do have a couple of little add-ons of their own, such as the GUI for the parser. In terms of provided models, the parser and tagger come with models for a range of languages, whereas CoreNLP ships only with English out of the box. However, you can then download language-particular jars for CoreNLP which provide all the models we have for different languages. Anything that is available in any of the releases is present in the CoreNLP github site: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple answer, I'm currently workin wih english only, and I always get confused about which tool I should add to my own project. I think I'll stick to CoreNLP for now. :)